# Is any alternative to z-index? (my pdf generator library probably does not support `z-index` tag)

Tags: html, css, xhtml2pdf

```
.line
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2
    top: 50px;
}
.otherclass
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

<div class="line">---</div>
<div class="otherclass"> my content </div>
```

Why `top` attribute not work? Is any alternative to z-index? (my pdf generator library probably does not support `z-index` tag)

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to generate PDF from HTML:

https://dpaste.de/2uZH

`top` from 70 line not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: `top` and `z-index` is not the same. Look into what the xmlhtml2pdf (if that is your generator) supports for CSS. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

There were older ways of doing this on the old Netscape but they are mostly gone now.  I think z-index is it.  Don't know what you are working on but I would keep in mind that html is not a page formatting language like pdf is.  That is why we have both.  html was designed to hint at what the browser should do.  So can you turn the z-index blocks into divs and have them flow above, below or to the side of the other content?